# Instagram Data Mining

Tags: javascript, php, instagram, instagram-api, data-mining

Есть вопрос: как собрать всех подписчиков определенного аккаунта Instagram?
Пробовал сам, получилось только со стороны клиента с помощью JS. Как реализовать это на стороне сервера - не знаю. Это явно реализуемо наглядный пример этого программа PromoFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас есть рабочий код на JS, то с относительно небольшими модификациями его можно запустить на NodeJS. Или взять готовый модуль [instagram-private-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api).

Вот пример поиска пользователя по нику с использованием этой библиотеки (взят [тут](https://toster.ru/q/416459)):

```
var Client = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
var device = new Client.Device('myuser');
var storage = new Client.CookieFileStorage(__dirname + '/cookies/myuser.json');

var user = 'login'
var pass = 'passwod';


Client.Session.create(device, storage, user, pass).then(session => {});

var session = new Client.Session(device, storage);

Client.Account.searchForUser(session, 'instagram')
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data._params);
  });
```

Для получения подписчиков нужно воспользоваться функцией `Client.Feed.AccountFollowers`